# SQL How to extract all possibles routes of a process

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table of process stages which store the process stage info. Each process stage can have one or more routes to the next stage, and this info is stored in an xml column with each stage.

e.g. stages sample data

```
stageId | stageXML
A | '<stage id="A"><routes><route id="1"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id>B</id></arguments></action></route><route id="2"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id>C</id></arguments></action></route><route id="3"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id>D</id></arguments></action></route></routes></stage>'
B | '<stage id="B"><routes><route id="1"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id>END</id></arguments></action></route></routes></stage>'
C | '<stage id="C"><routes><route id="1"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id>A</id></arguments></action></route></routes></stage>'
D | '<stage id="D"><routes><route id="1"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id/></arguments></action></route></routes></stage>'
```

SQL to create test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #stages
(stageId CHAR(1), stageXML xml)

INSERT INTO
  #stages(stageId,stageXML)
VALUES
('A' , '<stage id="A"><routes><route id="1"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id>B</id></arguments></action></route><route id="2"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id>C</id></arguments></action></route><route id="3"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id>D</id></arguments></action></route></routes></stage>'),
('B' , '<stage id="B"><routes><route id="1"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id>END</id></arguments></action></route></routes></stage>'),
('C' , '<stage id="C"><routes><route id="1"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id>A</id></arguments></action></route></routes></stage>'),
('D' , '<stage id="D"><routes><route id="1"><action><method>goToStage</method><arguments><id/></arguments></action></route></routes></stage>')

SELECT * from #stages
```

Each stage follows the goToStage method to the next stage until it hits a goToStage/id of 'END', or there isn't a next stage (no goToStage/id) OR the next stage is one already passed though.

So what I need to do is get out is the following result using  SQL Server 2008+: Note, the route column can be comma separated or xml or whatever as long as its usable.

```
stageId | route
A | B, END
A | C, A, END
A | D, END
```

I'm sure this can be done, but I'm struggling to get the SQL right, so any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
With a bit of tinkering, I have managed to extract the route data into the following format:

```
stageId | nextStageId
A | B
A | C
A | D
B | END
C | A
D |
```

using the SQL, maybe someone could help me create the routes from this if its easier.

```
SELECT  t.c.value('@id', 'VARCHAR(3)') AS stageId,
    t1.c1.value('.', 'VARCHAR(3)') AS nextStageId
FROM    #stages
CROSS APPLY stageXML.nodes('//stage') as T(C)
CROSS APPLY stageXML.nodes('//route/action/arguments/id') as T1(C1)
WHERE   stageXml.exist('//method[text()="goToStage"]') = 1
```

Comment: To make use of SQL, you should store the process stages in a separate table, with one row per route.  As you've structured the data, you need an xml function to parse everything you need, not a database.

Comment: I'm assuming that there is no way to change your data model to not store XML in a database?

Comment: unfortunately the database is already in use and cannot be changed. We currently use a Coldfusion script to generate these routes at present, but I'm sure it can be done with SQL. I've gotten close a few times.

Comment: I'm swinging at this, but can't figure out why you'd expect 'A | C, A, END' in your output. Should it be 'A | C, A, B, END'. Also, you've got a loop of A -> C -> A -> C... how do you expect that to be handled?

Comment: Your correct, it should be A| C, A, END sorry. Once a node has gone back to a previously visited node, it should end that path.

Answer (score 0):

There are loops in the data, and this is a computationally intractable problem in the general case. For instance, the route `C,A,B,END` leads to the route `C,A,C,A,B,END`, which leads to the route `C,A,C,A,C,A,B,END`, etc.

There is no way for SQL to do this without getting stuck in an infinite loop, because there are an infinite number of such strings in your non-directed route graph. (CTEs allow infinite recursion, but you would just crash your server.)